# Generate random 128 bit decimal in given range in go

Tags: go, random

Let's say that we have a random number generator that can generate random 32 or 64 bit integers (like [rand.Rand](https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/#Rand) in the standard library)

Generating a random int64 in a given range `[a,b]` is fairly easy:

```
rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
n := rand.Int63n(b-a) + a
```

Is it possible to generate random 128 bit decimal (as defined in specification IEEE 754-2008) in a given range from a combination of 32 or 64 bit random integers?

Comment: Is the intended output a bigInt?

Comment: @deef0000dragon1no the inteded output is Decimal 128 as defined in specification IEEE 754-2008, cf [bson decimal 128](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/bson-decimal128/decimal128.rst#terminology)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible, but by no means easy. Here is a sketch of a solution that might be acceptable — writing and debugging it would probably be at least a day of concerted effort.

Let `min` and `max` be [primitive.Decimal128](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive#Decimal128) objects from go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson. Let `MAXBITS` be a multiple of 32; 128 is likely to be adequate.

1. Get the significand (as big.Int) and exponent (as int) of `min` and `max` using the `BigInt` method.
2. Align min and max so that they have the same exponent. As far as possible, left-justify the value with the larger exponent by decreasing its exponent and adding a corresponding number of zeroes to the right side of its significand. If this would cause the absolute value of the significand to become >= `2**(MAXBITS-1)`, then either

   - (a) Right-shift the value with the smaller exponent by dropping digits from the right side of its significand and increasing its exponent, causing precision loss.
   - (b) Dynamically increase `MAXBITS`.
   - (c) Throw an error.
3. At this point both exponents will be the same, and both significands will be aligned big integers. Set aside the exponents for now, and let `range` (a new `big.Int`) be `maxSignificand - minSignificand`. It will be between 0 and `2**MAXBITS`.
4. Turn `range` into `MAXBITS/32` `uint32`s using the `Bytes` or `DivMod` methods, whatever is easier.
5. If the highest word of `range` is equal to `math.MaxUint32` then set a flag `limit` to `false`, otherwise `true`.
6. For n from 0 to `MAXBITS/32`:

   - if `limit` is true, use `rand.Int63n` (!, *not* `rand.Int31n` or `rand.Uint32`) to generate a value between 0 and the nth word of `range`, inclusive, cast it to `uint32`, and store it as the nth word of the output. If the value generated is equal to the nth word of `range` (i.e. if we generated the maximum possible random value for this word) then let `limit` remain true, otherwise set it false.
   - If `limit` is false, use `rand.Uint32` to generate the nth word of the output. `limit` remains false regardless of the generated value.
7. Combine the generated words into a `big.Int` by building a `[]byte` and using `big/Int.SetBytes` or multiplication and addition, as convenient.
8. Add the generated value to `minSignificand` to obtain the significand of the result.
9. Use `ParseDecimal128FromBigInt` with the result significand and the exponent from steps 2-3 to obtain the result.

The heart of the algorithm is step 6, which generates a uniform random unsigned integer of arbitrary length 32 bits at a time. The alignment in step 2 reduces the problem from a floating-point to an integer one, and the subtraction in step 3 reduces it to an *unsigned* one, so that we only have to think about one bound instead of 2. The `limit` flag records whether we're still dealing with that bound, or whether we've already narrowed the result down to an interval that doesn't include it.

Caveats:

1. I haven't written this, let alone tested it. I may have gotten it quite wrong. A sanity check by someone who does more numerical computation work than me would be welcome.
2. Generating numbers across a large dynamic range (including crossing zero) will lose some precision and omit some possible output values with smaller exponents unless a ludicrously large `MAXBITS` is used; however, 128 bits should give a result at least as good as a naive algorithm implemented in terms of decimal128.
3. The performance is probably pretty bad.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, but the solution is far from trivial. For a correct solution, there are several things to consider.

For one thing, values with exponent `E` are 10 times more likely than values with exponent `E - 1`.

Other issues include subnormal numbers and ranges that straddle zero.

I am aware of the [Rademacher Floating-Point Library](https://gitlab.com/christoph-conrads/rademacher-fpl), which [tackled this problem](https://gitlab.com/christoph-conrads/rademacher-fpl/blob/master/include/rademacher-fpl/impl/uniform-real-distribution.hpp) for binary floating-point numbers, but the solution there is complicated and its author has not yet written up how his algorithm works.

EDIT (May 11):

I have now specified an [algorithm](https://peteroupc.github.io/randomfunc.html#For_Floating_Point_Number_Formats) for generating random "uniform" floating-point numbers—

- In any range,
- with full coverage, and
- regardless of the digit base (such as binary or decimal).

Answer (score 1):

Go has a large number package that can do arbitrary length integers: https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/

It has a pseudo random number generator https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int.Rand, and the crypto package also has https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rand/#Int

You'd want to specify the max using https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int.Exp as `2^128`.

Can't speak to performance, though, or whether this is compliant if the IEEE standard, but large random numbers like what you'd use for UUIDs are possible.

Answer (score 1):

It depends how many values you want to generate. If it's enough to have no more 10^34 values in a specified range - it's quite simple.

As I see the problem, a random value in the range min..max can be calculated as random(0..1)*(max-min)+min

Look like we need to generate only decimal128 value in range 0..1. So it's a random value in range 0..10^34-1 with exponent -34. This value can be generated with a golang standard random package.

To multiply, add and substruct float128 values can be used golang math/big package with values normalization.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://github.com/PPerminov/random) is definitely what you are looking for.